# Find string in gatagrid view column

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, anonymous-function

I want to search a specific column for a specific string using **LINQ** , **Anonymous** methods  or **lambda expression.**

Comment: Good for you. Keep up the good work.

Comment: I think what Tim is trying to say is - could you give a bit more information...maybe on some of the things you've tried & the problems you had? ;-)

Comment: I did this by iterating that specific column and comparing each cell value.Now i want to do this smart way.

Answer (score 1):

**using LINQ**

Code below will return you all rows where a particular column `ColumnIndex` has value `ValueToFind`

```
List<DataGridViewRow> records = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows
                      where row.Cells[ColumnIndex].Value.ToString().Equals("ValueToFind")
                      select row).ToList();
```